# How Mage::throwException($error) working in below code?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, exception, transaction

In magento 1.9.1
In class "Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate"

consider below function uploadAndImport.
My question is : Mage::throwException($error) rollback transaction if there is error. But how? It is outside of try block? If we comment out code //Mage::throwException($error); then it will insert correct row data. And if we uncomment out then it will not insert any data ? how?

```
 public function uploadAndImport(Varien_Object $object)
{
    if (empty($_FILES['groups']['tmp_name']['tablerate']['fields']['import']['value'])) {
        return $this;
    }

    $csvFile = $_FILES['groups']['tmp_name']['tablerate']['fields']['import']['value'];
    $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($object->getScopeId());

    $this->_importWebsiteId     = (int)$website->getId();
    $this->_importUniqueHash    = array();
    $this->_importErrors        = array();
    $this->_importedRows        = 0;

    $io     = new Varien_Io_File();
    $info   = pathinfo($csvFile);
    $io->open(array('path' => $info['dirname']));
    $io->streamOpen($info['basename'], 'r');

    // check and skip headers
    $headers = $io->streamReadCsv();
    if ($headers === false || count($headers) < 5) {
        $io->streamClose();
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('shipping')->__('Invalid Table Rates File Format'));
    }

    if ($object->getData('groups/tablerate/fields/condition_name/inherit') == '1') {
        $conditionName = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/carriers/tablerate/condition_name');
    } else {
        $conditionName = $object->getData('groups/tablerate/fields/condition_name/value');
    }
    $this->_importConditionName = $conditionName;

    $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    $adapter->beginTransaction();

    try {
        $rowNumber  = 1;
        $importData = array();

        $this->_loadDirectoryCountries();
        $this->_loadDirectoryRegions();

        // delete old data by website and condition name
        $condition = array(
            'website_id = ?'     => $this->_importWebsiteId,
            'condition_name = ?' => $this->_importConditionName
        );
        $adapter->delete($this->getMainTable(), $condition);

        while (false !== ($csvLine = $io->streamReadCsv())) {
            $rowNumber ++;

            if (empty($csvLine)) {
                continue;
            }

            $row = $this->_getImportRow($csvLine, $rowNumber);
            if ($row !== false) {
                $importData[] = $row;
            }

            if (count($importData) == 5000) {
                $this->_saveImportData($importData);
                $importData = array();
            }
        }
        $this->_saveImportData($importData);
        $io->streamClose();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $adapter->rollback();
        $io->streamClose();
        Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $adapter->rollback();
        $io->streamClose();
        Mage::logException($e);
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('shipping')->__('An error occurred while import table rates.'));
    }

    $adapter->commit();

    if ($this->_importErrors) {
        $error = Mage::helper('shipping')->__('File has not been imported. See the following list of errors: %s', implode(" \n", $this->_importErrors));
        Mage::throwException($error);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The throw happens when there are elements in the `$this->_importErrors` array. These errors are not cause by throwing exceptions but by checks like making sure we have enough rows to import.

```
if ($this->_importErrors) {
    $error = Mage::helper('shipping')->__('File has not been imported. See the following list of errors: %s', implode(" \n", $this->_importErrors));
    Mage::throwException($error);
}
```

This is done in this way so that the import process will work with partial import. So if there is an error with row x then row y and row z will be imported but the user will get an error message with the information about row x and it's error.

In a way it is dealing with none fatal errors with the import as so has no real need to rollback.

**Update**

Because this is called as part of the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Shipping_Tablerate::_afterSave` then the whole thing is wrapped in a try catch as part of the `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` saving functionality.

Comment: I know if there is error in the csv file then it throws error. But $this->_saveImportData($importData); is called before checking error. So it should insert all the rows which does not have errors. If we comment out the code  Mage::throwException($error); then it will insert rows which does not contain error.

Comment: @PMB because it batches the rows using `$row = $this->_getImportRow($csvLine, $rowNumber);` there could be an error with one row, which allows the import to continue without the row with an error. Thus the commit is fine but the user should be informed.

Comment: if there is error in any row then it will not insert correct row data?

Comment: @PMB If you look at where `$this->_importErrors[] =` happens then you will see what sort of errors get added in here.

Comment: No. If we comment out code //Mage::throwException($error); then it will insert correct row data. And if we uncomment out then it will not insert any data ? how?

Comment: @PMB see my update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15907/discussion-between-pmb-and-david-manners).